# javascript syntax explanation (function () { } )();

Tags: javascript

i see the following code in a lot of java-script files.

```
(function () {
    //code goes here
})();
```

Can somebody explain this, or point me to a tutorial that explains this?

Comment: anonymous self-invoked function.

Comment: [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a code block, an immediately executing function to be exact, which basically prevents variables you define to leak into a global scope (which is a horrible thing and can lead to hard to track bugs)...

There is a good video you can watch on youtube [Fundamentals for Great jQuery Development](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcylSiDoOio) where a much more knowledgeable person goes over this technique in the first part of it. I advise you to watch it :)

*EDIT

Fixed the link to point to an intended video*